# Sphinx generates documentation partially

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

As a result of `make html` command, Sphinx generates documentation only for some modules. Other modules remain undocumented.

Project structure:

```
|- my-project
|--| my_project
|--| docs
|----| _build
|------| ...
|----| _static
|------| ...
|----| _templates
|------| ...
|---- conf.py
|---- index.rst
|---- Makefile
|---- source
|-----| modules.rst
|-----| ...
```

`conf.py`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
]
autosummary_generate=True
source_suffix = '.rst'
```

`index.rst`:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   ./source/modules


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

`source/modules.rst`:

```
my_project
==========

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   my_project
```

Please consider to look at the sources at github: https://github.com/mxmaslin/Test-tasks/tree/removeme/tests_python/my-project

Comment: How do you install your project? There's no setup.py or pip requirements file. If your project is not installed, I think that's why you get all the import errors.

Comment: In `prediction/models/__init__.py`, one of the import statements is `from baseline.median import MedianForecaster`. Shouldn't that be `from my_project.prediction.models.baseline.median import MedianForecaster`?. Or perhaps simply `from .baseline.median import MedianForecaster` (dot added for relative import)?

Comment: I’ve put setup.py to repo. Please consider to look

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a MINIMAL test case ([mcve])? The GitHub project is quite large and confusing (to me at least...).

Comment: Thanks, @mzjn! Your comment regarding imports solved my issue! You are great!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in incorrect imports. Thanks to @mzjn for pointing this